# Selenium WebdriverIO execute command fails

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am creating a series of Javascript automated tests using Javascript 
 / Selenium / WebdriverIO. I am having serious trouble with WebdriverIO's 'execute' command. The command 'execute' is being used due to a fundamental problem whereby an element not in the visible area of a window is not clickable, rendering the automation useless as it fails everytime. To overcome this viewable area issue I'm using 'execute' to 'scrollIntoView' any troublesome element before the 'click' command is called. In simple situations this works fine. Multiple sequential execute commands work unless separated by a click which navigates from PageA to PageB. This navigation seems to break the execute flow. My thoughts are that the execute Javascript is maybe injected into the current page, therefore the navigation destoys the script. I'm really not sure!

Has anyone else had issues like this? If so, please help, its driving me nuts!!

this code works :

```
module.exports = {
    runMacro: function(){
        browser
            .execute(function() {
                var els = document.getElementsByClassName('img-cnt');
                els[0].scrollIntoView();
            })
            .pause(3000) // for testing purposes
            .execute(function() {
                // this code executes
            })
    }
};
```

this code doesn't work :

```
module.exports = {
    runMacro: function(){
        browser
            .execute(function() {
                var els = document.getElementsByClassName('img-cnt');
                els[0].scrollIntoView();
            })
            .click('.img-cnt')
            .pause(3000) // for testing purposes - in real test would for waitForExists or similar
            .execute(function() {
                 // this code doesn't execute
            })
    }
};
```

thanks!!!!

Comment: Before answering your question, I'm curious regarding why haven't your tried to **[.scroll()](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/scroll.html)** to your *problematic element*. Btw, for me, whenever I have to click on an element that is not visible within the view-port, the `.click()` also scrolls the view to it's location, out-of-the-box. Anyways, `.execute()` is hackish and should be avoided. I'd consider trying other ways to do it.

Comment: `.scroll()` just doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if its because I'm in standalone mode. `.click()` doesn't scroll to the element automatically. Again, could be a standalone issue.. but I definitely have to manually `scroll` to the element before i can click on it. I agree, execute does feel hackish but I'm out of options due to the above.